# FTPS using (import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient) getting 550 Failed to open file

Tags: java, ftp-client

I am using Ubuntu and for FTPS using vsftpd
Getting below error for ftps using java. I checked I have permission on ftpuser directory

```
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
AUTH TLS
234 Proceed with negotiation.
PROT P
200 PROT now Private.
Connected to localhost.
USER ftpuser
331 Please specify the password.
PASS ftpuser
230 Login successful.
SYST
215 UNIX Type: L8
Remote system is UNIX Type: L8
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,156,154).
RETR /home/ftpuser/remote/a.txt
550 Failed to open file.
QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

Comment: Got the issue remote file path should w.r.to ftpuser home directory

Comment: Try checking `/etc/vsftpd/user_list` and `/etc/vsftpd/ftpusers` to see if you have permissions, if you haven't done that already